# Find closest image on multiple divs with same class

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble selecting specific divs and replacing their images with jQuery.

I have content that is being bought in dynamically with php via a while or for loop. Below, the div with the class "defPostThumb" is the only thing I can control. Everything else is dynamic. This said, essentially the content structure will look something like this below:

```
<div class="postWrapper">
  <div class="defPostThumb"><img src="defaultThm.jpg"></div>
  <div class="PostContent">
  <h1>Content here</h1>
  <img src="IMAGE-ONE.jpg" alt="">
  RAW TEXT HERE
</div>

//------

<div class="postWrapper">
  <div class="defPostThumb"><img src="defaultThm.jpg"></div>
  <div class="PostContent">
  <h1>Content here</h1>
  <img src="IMAGE-TWO.jpg" alt="">
  RAW TEXT HERE
</div>

 //------


<div class="postWrapper">
  <div class="defPostThumb"><img src="defaultThm.jpg"></div>
  <div class="PostContent">
  <h1>Content here</h1>
  <img src="IMAGE-THREE.jpg" alt="">
  RAW TEXT HERE
</div>
```

Since the content is being bought in dynamically in raw-ish form, I put in a placeholder image called "**defaultThm.jpg**" which is located in the div with a class of "**defPostThumb**".

What I want to do is to create a thumbnail for each code block or section of content based off of the first image that jQuery finds inside the div **PostContent**.

Essentially, since I don't know what that image or source is going to be, I copy the source of the first image that I've found inside the PostContent div, and append it to the placeholder image.

So far I've been able to get close by writing this below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this is a div to hold my own thumbnails
    var defPostThumb = $('.defPostThumb img');
    //this finds the img tag src on the content div from the feed
    var imgThm = $('.PostContent').find("img").attr("src");
    defPostThumb.attr('src', imgThm);
});
```

Although it works (partially), what's happening is that it is going to the first content block, finding the first image and copying its source (like I wanted it to), and appending it to ALL the default thumb images on ALL code blocks (not what I wanted)

What needs to happen is that, I want to keep that search local to each code block.

I tried with code like:

```
var imgThm = $('.feedContActual').parent().find("img").attr("src");
```

etc but it's not good.

I want every content block, to search locally for the first image it finds, and append that image source to the default image src INSIDE of their parent div.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of different ways you can do this (some more flexible than others).

One way is to select a common parent and then traverse from that. For instance, the `postWrapper` element would look something like this:

```
$('.postWrapper').each(function(){
    var src = $(this).find('.PostContent img:first').attr('src');
    $(this).find('.defPostThumb img').attr('src', src);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r6y6gehz/

How about working from the thumbnail images? Something like this:

```
$('img[src="defaultThm.jpg"]').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).parent().next().find('img').attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cx0ugdqL/

Or this:

```
$('img[src="defaultThm.jpg"]').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).closest('.postWrapper').find('.PostContent img:first').attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mkgh9v3L/

If you're not a fan of `each` (or just prefer jQuery's `implicit iteration` to get things done), how about this:

```
$('img[src="defaultThm.jpg"]').attr('src', function(){
    return $(this).parent().next().find('img').attr('src');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0jjwf1hk/

So a lot of ways to accomplish the same thing. One thing you'll hopefully notice is that some `DOM traversing` is more "flexible" than others. Calling `next` requires/assumes a certain order of elements, where as selecting a common parent and finding the images is much more loose/flexible.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you. I've been messing with this for TOO long lol. Great answer and examples. Again thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Jquery [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method for every `.Postcontent`, then change the `src` of the `.defPostThumb img` contained in its [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

```js
$('.PostContent').each(function(){
    var imgThm = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    $(this).parent().find('.defPostThumb img').attr('src', imgThm);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postWrapper">
  <div class="defPostThumb"><img src="defaultThm.jpg"></div>
  <div class="PostContent">
  <h1>Content here</h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" alt="">
  RAW TEXT HERE
</div>

//------

<div class="postWrapper">
  <div class="defPostThumb"><img src="defaultThm.jpg"></div>
  <div class="PostContent">
  <h1>Content here</h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/51/50" alt="">
  RAW TEXT HERE
</div>

 //------


<div class="postWrapper">
  <div class="defPostThumb"><img src="defaultThm.jpg"></div>
  <div class="PostContent">
  <h1>Content here</h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/52/50" alt="">
  RAW TEXT HERE
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
$(".defPostThumb img").map(function(i, el) {
  $(el).attr("src", $(".postWrapper").eq(i).find("img").not(el).attr("src"))
});
```

```css
.defPostThumb img {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="postWrapper">
  <div class="defPostThumb"><img src="defaultThm.jpg"></div>
  <div class="PostContent">
  <h1>Content here</h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/?1" alt="">
  RAW TEXT HERE
</div>

<div class="postWrapper">
  <div class="defPostThumb"><img src="defaultThm.jpg"></div>
  <div class="PostContent">
  <h1>Content here</h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/?2" alt="">
  RAW TEXT HERE
</div>

<div class="postWrapper">
  <div class="defPostThumb"><img src="defaultThm.jpg"></div>
  <div class="PostContent">
  <h1>Content here</h1>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/?3" alt="">
  RAW TEXT HERE
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.defPostThumb img').each(function(i, img) {
        img.src = $(this).closest(".postWrapper").find(".PostContent img")[0].src;
    });
});
```